# SqlConnection object in DLL throwing "Keyword not supported" exception on instantiation

Tags: c#, sql, dll, connection-string

I wrote a .dll that is to be used to connect to a SQL database. The code works fine when it was simply a class file in another Visual Studio project. However, now that I am attempting to use it as a .dll in another, this line throws an unhandled "ArgumentExcpetion":

```
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

What gets me is the text in the exception message box.

```
Keyword not supported: '<comp name>\sqlexpress;initial catalog'.
```

This is the same connection string I used in another program to connect to the SQL database on my local machine. I can look in the "Locals" window while I'm debugging in VS 2010, and The connection string looks exactly the same as it does in other projects I've used (in fact, I simply copied and pasted it)

```
"<comp name>\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AgentResources;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Here is how the object is instantiated and the connection string added.

```
BatchRecord record = new BatchRecord("DEV", "TEST");

record.ConnString = "<comp name>\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AgentResources;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
```

Comment: Where is the connection string coming from? A configuration file?

Comment: Since I'm testing I'm adding it manually, however eventually it will be pulled from a config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That connection string is not valid. It should be

```
 Data Source=<comp name>\\SQLEXPRESS;
```

Comment: Unfortunately now the error message reads "datasource" as being the unsupported keyword.

Comment: Forget that comment, I needed to put a space between Data and Source. Time for me to go home :)